# NSDictionary file emailed different than same file in app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, nsdictionary

In my app, I store about 6 different keys in an NSDictionary and store that dictionary as a file so that it can be sent to other users of the app. Three of my keys are numbers that I store as strings: (for example)

```
 NSString *altitudeData = [NSString stringWithFormat:%1.50f",_altitude];
 [mutableDict setObject:altitudeData forKey:@"altitude"];
 [mutableDict writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

I zip it up with some relevant media files and send it.

Usually everything works fine. The app receives the zipped file, unzips it, reads the NSDictionary file (which is basically an XML) and creates an object based off of the information it just received.

However things do not work right consistently. This problem has me particularly baffled because I had the same exact file sent to my app and to my computer. The keys that were numbers I had stored as strings (like my example above) are changed to 0.00000……… in the file my app reads.

```
 <key>altitude</key>
 <string>0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000</string>
```

I open the NSDictionary as an XML on my computer though and I can clearly see that they are correct and as they were when I exported them.

```
 <key>altitude</key>
 <string>27.19356918334960937500000000000000000000000000000000</string>
```

I have confirmed several times that these are indeed the same file, and everything else is the same. I've also tried erasing my app and re-running to make sure I wasn't accidentally reading the wrong file. How and why are these fields transformed? Is there anything I can do to prevent it?

**edit:In response to a request about how I'm zipping the file**
I'm actually using some code I imported from github for that purpose

```
     //first locate temp directory
     NSString *tmpDirectory = NSTemporaryDirectory();
     NSMutableString *fileNameOfZip = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@.zip",_name];
     [fileNameOfZip replaceOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"_" options:NSBackwardsSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, fileNameOfZip.length)];
     NSString *zipFilePath = [tmpDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                              fileNameOfZip];

     //then find all files related to zipping
     NSString *mainFilePath = [FILE_DIR stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.xml",_name]];
     NSString *imageFilePath = [self saveImages];
     NSString *videoFilePath = [self saveVideo];
     NSString *audioFilePath = [self saveAudio];
     NSMutableArray *filesToAdd = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects: nil];
     [filesToAdd addObject:mainFilePath];
     [filesToAdd addObject:imageFilePath];
     [filesToAdd addObject:videoFilePath];
     [filesToAdd addObject:audioFilePath];
     ////HERE IS THE CLASS IMPORTED FROM github
     bool successful_zip = [SSZipArchive createZipFileAtPath:zipFilePath withFilesAtPaths:filesToAdd];
```

**to unzip:**

```
     NSData *fileAsData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:file];
     NSString *urlAsString = file.absoluteString;
     NSArray *brokenFile = [urlAsString componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
     NSString *fileName = [brokenFile lastObject];
     NSString *buildPath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"constructing"];
     createDirectory(buildPath);
     NSString *filePath = [buildPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
     [fileAsData writeToFile:filePath atomically:NO];
     ////HERE IS THE CLASS IMPORTED FROM github
     bool upziped = [SSZipArchive unzipFileAtPath:filePath toDestination:buildPath];
     if (upziped) {
         NSLog(@"unzipped");
     }
     else {
         NSLog(@"not unzipped");
     }
     NSArray* buildDirectory = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:buildPath error:NULL];

     //import NSDictionary file
     ObjectItem *object = nil; /* This is the object I'm re-creating with my file*/
     for (NSString*s in buildDirectory) {
         NSLog(@"files here: %@",s);
         if ([s rangeOfString:@".xml"].location != NSNotFound) {
             NSString *name = [[s componentsSeparatedByString:@"."]firstObject];
             object = [ObjectItem retrieveFromName:name];
             break;
         }
     }

     //import image
     UIImage *image;
     for (NSString *media in buildDirectory) {
         if ([media rangeOfString:@".png"].location != NSNotFound) {
             NSString *imageFilePath = [buildPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:media];
             image = [[UIImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:imageFilePath];
             [object importImage:image];
             break;
         }
     }

     //import video
     for (NSString *media in buildDirectory) {
         if ([media rangeOfString:@".MOV"].location != NSNotFound) {
             NSString *videoFilePath = [buildPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:media];
             [object importVideo:videoFilePath];
             break;
         }
     }

     //import audio
     NSString *audioExt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@".%@",AUDIO_EXT];
     for (NSString *media in buildDirectory) {
         if ([media rangeOfString:audioExt].location != NSNotFound) {
             NSString *audioFilePath = [buildPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:media];
             [object importAudio:audioFilePath];
             break;
         }
     }

     [object save];
```

**Also incase it's helpful here the [ObjectItem retrieveFromName] method**

```
 +(ObjectItem
      *)retrieveFromName:(NSString*)name {
     NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
     NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
     NSString *subDirectory = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ObjectItems"];
     createDirectory(subDirectory);
     NSString *filePath = [subDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.xml",name]];
     NSString *file = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:nil];
     NSLog(@"file contents:\n%@\n",file);
     file = nil;
     NSDictionary *myDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
     for (NSString *s in myDict) {
         NSLog(@"key \"%@\" has value: %@",s,[myDict objectForKey:s]);
     }
     double lat = [[myDict objectForKey:@"latitude"]doubleValue];
     double lon = [[myDict objectForKey:@"longitude"]doubleValue];
     double alt = [[myDict objectForKey:@"altitude"]doubleValue];
     CLLocation *loc = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lon)
                                                    altitude:alt
                                          horizontalAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
                                            verticalAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
                                                   timestamp:[NSDate date]];
     UIImage *im = nil;
     NSString *vid = nil;
     NSString *aud = nil;

     ObjectItem
       *object
       = [[ObjectItem
       alloc]initWithName:name location:loc];
     NSString *key = [myDict objectForKey:@"image"];
     if (key != nil) {
         im = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:key];
         [object
       importImage:[im copy]];
     }
     key = nil;
     key = [myDict objectForKey:@"video"];
     if (key != nil) {
         vid = [NSString stringWithString:key];
         [object
       importVideo:[vid copy]];
     }
     key = nil;
     key = [myDict objectForKey:@"audio"];
     if (key != nil) {
         aud = [NSString stringWithString:key];
         [object
       importAudio:[aud copy]];
     }
     paths = nil;
     documentsDirectory = subDirectory = filePath = nil;
     im = nil;
     vid = nil;
     aud = nil;
     myDict = nil;
     key = nil;
     return object
      ;
 }
```

Comment: Side note - why 50 decimal places? A `double` is only good to about 13 or 14 significant digits.

Comment: You're right. I guess that is a little overkill. I was experiencing some errors caused by a lack of precision and I might have overcompensated a little.

Comment: We have no idea where you are getting _altitude from. We need to see more code.

Comment: Does it really matter? As I understand the question, the values are written correctly, as verified on the desktop machine. @dev574, are you 100 % sure the values are written correctly? It would be quite mysterious for them to change afterwards.

Comment: I don't see a way to help except to say that values in files don't spontaneously change.  Getting to the bottom of this is going to be all about what you mean by "I zip it up and send it to my app" and "I send the same file to my computer".  Please restate those sentences with code (and NSLog output) The other commenter prompted you to post irrelevant code.  Feel free to remove it.  (In other words, please add content that says:  here's NSLog output before I send.  Here's how I zip and send, here's differing log output on the receiving end).

Comment: @zoul I've just doubled and triple-checked. It's happening to three of my files. One after the other I open them in my app and I get the 0000s. Then I email them to my computer and open them and they are the altitudes they should be.

Comment: @ dahn Thanks, coming right up.

Comment: @danh Looks like I can't reproduce the problem with any file I've created today, so I can't get you any print statements. I'm using the MFMessageComposeViewController to send the zip files as SMS messages to myself right now. From there I can open the attachment in my app or with the Mail app. I open it in the mail app to send it to my computer. I know this is a lot, and this is a really weird problem. I appreciate everyone looking at it.

Comment: @dev574 FYI - my original comment was off a bit. It's more like 15 or 16 digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wish the answer was something profound, but unfortunately the cause was a result of lazy programming. There are two places in my app where I recreate my `ObjectItem` using a file. In one I'm recreating the object from information in the Document's folder, and in the other I'm recreating from information in the temp.

The method I was using to recreate objects from files, (which I have above) `+(ObjectItem*)retrieveFromName:` was always looking in the Document folder. When it didn't see the file there there my app would re-create my `ObjectItem` with no altitude/coordinates and produce a corresponding file in the Document folder.